# Access contacts and get email address

Tags: android, email, contacts

I have a code snippet for accessing to Contacts. When user click the button then the contacts list will be open and user can choose a person from contacts and the person's email address should be write on a edittext. I can receive the email from the persons which user select. But I can't set it to the edittext.

```
static String email = "";


imgbtnaddfromcontacts.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (v == imgbtnaddfromcontacts) {
                    try 
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.e("Error in intent : ", e.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        kimeTxt.setText(email);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

        try {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // Get data
                Uri contactData = data.getData();
                // Cursor
                Cursor cur = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                ContentResolver contect_resolver = getContentResolver();

                // List
                if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                    String id = cur
                            .getString(cur
                                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

                    Cursor phoneCur = contect_resolver.query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                    + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);

                    Cursor emailCur = contect_resolver.query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID
                                    + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);

                    if (phoneCur.moveToFirst()) {
                        name = phoneCur
                                .getString(phoneCur
                                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                        no = phoneCur
                                .getString(phoneCur
                                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                    }

                    while (emailCur.moveToNext()) {
                        // This would allow you get several email addresses
                        // if the email addresses were stored in an array
                        email = emailCur
                                .getString(emailCur
                                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));

                        if (email != null) 
                        {
                            seciliEmail = email;
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(EpostaIletActivity.this,
                                    "Kişinin eposta hesabı bulunmamaktadır.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            Log.w("Error: ", "Kişinin eposta hesabı yok.");
                        }
                    }

                    Log.e("Phone no & name & email :***: ", name + " : " + no + ":" + email);
                    // txt.append(name + " : " + no + "\n");

                    id = null;
                    name = null;
                    no = null;
                    seciliEmail = "xxx";
                    phoneCur = null;
                    emailCur.close();
                }
                contect_resolver = null;
                cur = null;
                // populateContacts();

            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("IllegalArgumentException :: ", e.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Error :: ", e.toString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

make sure your app has got permission, otherwise you'll get weird Exceptions

in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can achieve it like this     

   public class Abc extends Activity{
        EditText kimeTxt;
            Intent i;                                  
              Bundle b ;    
            @Override  

            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.add_course);
        kimeTxt= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.emailid);

        }


        @Override
            public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

                try {
                    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        // Get data
                        Uri contactData = data.getData();
                        // Cursor
                        Cursor cur = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                        ContentResolver contect_resolver = getContentResolver();

                        // List
                        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                            String id = cur
                                    .getString(cur
                                            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

                            Cursor phoneCur = contect_resolver.query(
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                    null,
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                            + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);

                            Cursor emailCur = contect_resolver.query(
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                                    null,
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID
                                            + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);

                            if (phoneCur.moveToFirst()) {
                                name = phoneCur
                                        .getString(phoneCur
                                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                                no = phoneCur
                                        .getString(phoneCur
                                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                            }

                            while (emailCur.moveToNext()) {
                                // This would allow you get several email addresses
                                // if the email addresses were stored in an array
                                email = emailCur
                                        .getString(emailCur
                                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));

                                if (email != null) 
                                {
                                    seciliEmail = email;
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(EpostaIletActivity.this,
                                            "Kişinin eposta hesabı bulunmamaktadır.",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                    Log.w("Error: ", "Kişinin eposta hesabı yok.");
                                }
                            }

                            Log.e("Phone no & name & email :***: ", name + " : " + no + ":" + email);
                            // txt.append(name + " : " + no + "\n");

                            id = null;
                            name = null;
                            no = null;
                            seciliEmail = "xxx";
                            phoneCur = null;
                            emailCur.close();
                        }


    // can set email id here 



      kimeTxt.setText(email);


                        contect_resolver = null;
                        cur = null;
                        // populateContacts();

                    }
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("IllegalArgumentException :: ", e.toString());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("Error :: ", e.toString());
                }
        }
```